# How to find the text of an <input type="text"/> when the string is not set to the field's value?

Tags: jquery, html

**Scenario**

I have an input field of type "text". But when I type something in it, the field's `value` attribute does not change.

I'm trying to use jQuery to locate this input element by its value, but that's tricky when the text is seemingly not stored in the element itself.

So I'll have something that looks like this:

[image]

But inspecting the element I get

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value class="some_text_field">
```

**Question**

How can I use jQuery to locate a text input whose value has changed by typing into it, but the internal value of the object is empty?

Comment: value is something you should not be using as a selector. If you want to find something by the value, than you will need to select inputs and filter them.

Comment: @epascarello - That's a valid concern, but I really have no other way to differentiate between these fields.

Comment: I guess an alternate question would be; can I dynamically set the field's value to be equal to its text?

Comment: Seems weird you would be selecting an element by its value. Can you update the attribute, sure, onchange, set the attribute. Still not sure why you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` (read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)) and a callback function to return text inputs with a lookup value.

In it's simplest form...

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function () {
  return this.value == 'your search value'
})
```

Comment: I'm not at the computer at the moment, but this seems to be predicated on the element's value as well? Or does this seach the field's innertext?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you refer to as the elements value and inner text? An input field only has a value.